# How can I read dates without year using readr?

Tags: r, readr

I have a data file in which dates are given without year.

```
01/05   Fellowship enters Moria
01/09   Fellowship reaches Lorien
01/17   Passing of Gandalf
02/07   Fellowship leaves Lorien
02/17   Death of Boromir
```

I try to read it like this

```
lotr <- read_tsv(lotr_file,
                 skip = 9,
                 col_names = c("date", "event"),
                 col_types = cols(
                    date = col_date(format = "%m/%d"),
                    event = col_character()))
```

but it seams that the date parser of readr cannot parse dates without a year. On the other hand, lubridate can handle such dates:

```
> parse_date_time("12-15", "%m-%d")
[1] "0000-12-15 UTC"
```

Is there any way that readr can read such dates or can use lubridate?

If readr cannot handle such "dates" or day of year, I would use dplyr in the following way:

```
lotr <- read_tsv(lotr_file,
                 skip = 9,
                 n_max = 37,
                 col_names = c("day_of_year", "event"),
                 col_types = cols(
                   day_of_year = col_character(),
                   event = col_character())) %>% 
   mutate(date = parse_date(paste0("2016/",day_of_year))) %>% 
   select(date, event)
```

Comment: You'll have to add a year after you read it.  A date is not a date without a year.

Comment: ...specifically, read it as a character column, `paste()` a year on the front and then parse.

Comment: Thank you. Instead of date, I should've written e.g. day of year. My question was whether readr could handle this kind of "date". I've added some code to my question showing how I would do it without build-in readr functionality

Answer (score 2):

As Rich pointed in the comments, a "date" without a year is not valid as you need year, month and date.

Questions like this have come up before, and the answer is to just add *a* value of the missing type, be it a *day* to month and year, or here a *year* to day and month.

See eg

```
R> vals <- c("01/05", "01/09", "01/17", "02/07", "02/17")  # values
R> yval <- paste0("2000/", vals)  # prefix a year 
R> anytime::anydate(yval)    # needs no format
[1] "2000-01-05" "2000-01-09" "2000-01-17" "2000-02-07" "2000-02-17"
R>
```

That you have them you can format, or compute differences, or ...  Two examples:

```
R> diff(anytime::anydate(yval))
Time differences in days
[1]  4  8 21 10
R> format(anytime::anydate(yval), "%d-%b")
[1] "05-Jan" "09-Jan" "17-Jan" "07-Feb" "17-Feb"
R>
```

Comment: Thank you. Instead of date, I should've written e.g. day of year. My question was whether readr could handle this kind of "date". I've added some code to my question showing how I would do it without build-in readr functionality

Comment: So you still insist that 'month and year' form a date. They don't.